# I can't use vmware on rdp win server error hyper-v

Tags: windows, hyper-v, rdp, vmware-workstation

I've rdp win 12 azure install Vmware 16 pro on it
and setup the app to when try run virtual machine get error that hyper-v turn off
when check it it's already off
and use all commands like hyper-v and use command bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off  and core isolation integry off
this is my rdp info

OS Name Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
Version 10.0.17763 Build 17763
Other OS Description Not Available
OS Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Name python
System Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
System Model Virtual Machine
System Type x64-based PC
System SKU Unsupported
Processor Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8171M CPU @ 2.60GHz, 2095 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 090008, 12/7/2018
SMBIOS Version 2.3
BIOS Mode Legacy
BaseBoard Manufacturer Microsoft Corporation
BaseBoard Product Virtual Machine
BaseBoard Version 7.0
Platform Role Desktop
Secure Boot State Unsupported
PCR7 Configuration Binding Not Possible
Windows Directory C:\Windows
System Directory C:\Windows\system32
Boot Device \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Locale United States
Hardware Abstraction Layer Version = "10.0.17763.2061"
User Name Not Available
Time Zone Coordinated Universal Time
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16.0 GB
Total Physical Memory 16.0 GB
Available Physical Memory 13.4 GB
Total Virtual Memory 18.9 GB
Available Virtual Memory 16.4 GB
Page File Space 2.88 GB
Page File D:\pagefile.sys
Kernel DMA Protection Off
Virtualization-based security Not enabled
Device Encryption Support Reasons for failed automatic device encryption: Feature is not available, TPM is not usable, PCR7 binding is not supported, Hardware Security Test Interface failed and device is not InstantGo, Un-allowed DMA capable bus/device(s) detected, WinRE is not configured, TPM is not usable
A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

please help

Answer (score 2):

Nested virtualization is [not supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization#3rd-party-virtualization-apps) for VMware in Azure virtual machines.

> Virtualization applications other than Hyper-V are not supported in Hyper-V virtual machines, and are likely to fail. This includes any software that requires hardware virtualization extensions.